# How can I generate PDF metadata from LaTeX?

Tags: pdf, pdftex, miktex, metadata

I am writing a document using LaTeX and generating PDF.  Can anybody tell me how I can generate the PDF metadata, e.g. author or title, from LaTeX?  On Windows XP, I am using MikTex's texify to generate the PDF.  On linux, I am using pdflatex to generate the PDF.  Any answers for either platform would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Use the `hyperref` package, included in pretty much every latex distribution these days.

```
\usepackage[pdftex,
            pdfauthor={Your Name},
            pdftitle={The Title},
            pdfsubject={The Subject},
            pdfkeywords={Some Keywords},
            pdfproducer={Latex with hyperref, or other system},
            pdfcreator={pdflatex, or other tool}]{hyperref}
```

Comment: it might be worth adding a note that this is the better answer, especially if using Xe[La]TeX

Comment: What's the difference between `pdfproducer` and `pdfcreator`?

Comment: What's the difference between your two solutions?
@Brent.Longborough why this solution is better?

Comment: @red The other one's in an alien format; one more piece of (IMO) unnecessary brain overload.

Comment: Isn't pdfproducer and pdfcreator set automatically? At least this seems to be the case for me...

Comment: Do you really need the switch 'pdftex' to make it work? I tried without and writing metadata  worked.

Comment: All of these options (and more) are documented (with their default values) in the hyperref manual, section [3.9 Big alphabetical list](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.html#x1-130003.9).

Comment: You may also want to use `pdfusetitle` hyperref option to automatically use `\title` and `\author` as said by @Chris.

Comment: Just curious: by _default_, there is absolutely no metadata created, right? So it would be completely unnecessary to use `\usepackage[pdftex,pdfauthor={}]{hyperref}` just so that to wipe out my name, right?

Comment: @lpdbw you may find the explanation [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/590921/133604) useful.

Comment: Is pdftex necassary?

Comment: `pdftex` is not necessary, as it can be autodetected. See https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.html#x1-80003.4 which discusses driver options. Some drivers can be autodetected, and some can't. `pdftex` is one of the ones that can.

Answer (score 67):

As others have already answered, I like to use `hyperref`. However, as my documents often have `\author` and `\title` commands I do not want to repeat myself in the package parameters. Luckily, `hyperref` also has a parameter for that. If you want it to read the information from your `\author` and similar tags, simply include it like this:

```
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
```

Note: As commented by @hmijail, this option might be gone in future versions of the `hyperref` package. See also a [GitHub comment of one of the package maintainters](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/169#issuecomment-772524539).

Comment: That is a nice option, but if you're using several \author tags it only seems to include the last one.

Comment: Which version of hyperref has this option? Version from Jan 2017 does not seem to.

Comment: @IlyaPopov which version exactly do you use? It works for me with current version `2018/02/06 v6.86b` and I doubt very much it does not work with "Jan 2017" version.

Comment: I tested with `2012/11/06 v6.83m` from TeXLive 2015 and it works too. It seems very improbable it ceased working in-between that version and current one.

Comment: @jfbu Indeed it works, although is not documented in the hyperref manual. Thanks!

Comment: @IlyaPopov its is documented in the README: you need to click on the triangle next to "Hyperref manual" bookmark, then click on README. You find it in table of contents and on page 13 of file with title `README for hyperref bundle`.

Comment: @jfbu Oh, I see now. So, it is documented in `README`, but not in the `manual.pdf` for some reason.

Comment: @IlyaPopov this is also the case of important other things such as  `bookmarksdepth` for example.

Comment: The [hyperref](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) manual for hyperref 2018/11/30 v6.88e does mention the `pdfusetitle` option (*New Features, Option pdfusetitle*). Also, using `\title{\texorpdfstring{for \LaTeX\ output}{for PDF metadata}}` and similar markup for `\author` can be wise if you have formatting instructions in your `\title` or `\author` (although `hyperref` seems to be smart about at least ``\\`` and babel-french's `\bsc` command).

Comment: As of 2024, there are multiple issues in the hyperref repo pointing to pdfusetitle being problematic and being on its way out. Probably best to use other options. https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/169

Answer (score 48):

Use the `\pdfinfo` macro, where the contents are given in PDF notation:

```
\pdfinfo{
   /Author (Nicola Talbot)
   /Title  (Creating a PDF document using PDFLaTeX)
   /CreationDate (D:20040502195600)
   /Subject (PDFLaTeX)
   /Keywords (PDF;LaTeX)
}
```

(Source: http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/pdfdoc/pdfdoc/pdfdoc.html)

Comment: In combination with [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref?lang=en) package it might cause some problems like described [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48070/109417). Just wanted to mention this, since I just experienced the same problem.

Comment: Unless all of the metadata is Latin-1, there may be problems if you use `\pdfinfo` directly. This is because the data must be encoded in a certain way, which is not what you would expect for other languages. Package `hyperref` does the necessary encoding. Similarly for XMP, which must be encoded utf-8 with a few characters escaped (because they are active characters in PDF).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `xmpincl`, "which allows you to add arbitrary metadata in the Adobe XMP (Extensible Metadata Platform) format. But you have to write a separate XML file to do this" (suggested in threads [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5958/is-hyperref-really-the-best-way-to-add-metadata-to-a-tex-file)). They also propose a more recent package `hyperxmp`.

You can find an example .xmpdata file and other files needed on [creating high-quality PDF/A documents using LaTeX](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/pdfa/).

This instruction not only provides files that work better than TeXLive standard packages for inclusion of metadata (they fixed some bugs), but also shows how to create PDF/A which has very good properties optimized for long-term archiving.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason none of the solutions here worked for me.
I tried with this and it worked:

```
\AfterPreamble{\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={John Doe},
  pdftitle={The Title},
  pdfsubject={The Subject}
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

*You explicitly asked for generating the metadata from LaTeX, and using one of the answers of Ken Bloom seems the right way for me.*

For the case that you want to add metadata to a file not created with LaTex (or an existing pdf you do not want to recompile) I just wanted to point you to http://www.bureausoft.com/products.html#PDF%20Info%20%28Freeware%29 
which is a free Windows programme to change the pdf metadata. (I do not recommend this instead of the pdfLaTeX way!)

Comment: For this you can even use the `hyperref` package as stated above in a blank document where you just _import_ your desired PDF using the `pdfpages` package.