# pdfinfo doesn't appear to be working

Tags: metadata

I'm compiling my LaTeX using pdflatex and would like to have some pdfinfo integrated into the resulting file. Alas, this doesn't seem to be working, though I am using the same code which has worked in the past.

The header of my source is below:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\newcommand{\final}{1}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{abstract}

\title{Zombie Paranoia in the Bronx: A Study in Psychosocial Perceptions \\ Draft}

\author{{\bfseries John Smith$^a$} \\
{\footnotesize $^a$Ecology, Evolution, \& Behavior, University of Queens, USA \emph{smith@uoq.edu}}\\
}
\date{}

\pdfinfo
{ /Title (Zombie Paranoia in the Bronx: A Study in Psychosocial Perceptions)
  /Author (John Smith)
%  /CreationDate (D:YYYYMMDDhhmmss) % this is the format used by pdf for date/time
%  /Subject (...)
%  /Keywords ()
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is caused by the `hyperref` package. It's not needed in your example, so you could just delete it. However, if your whole document does need `hyperref`, you can use `\hypersetup` to include the information.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\title{Zombie Paranoia in the Bronx: A Study in Psychosocial Perceptions \\ Draft}
\author{{\bfseries John Smith$^a$} \\
{\footnotesize $^a$Ecology, Evolution, \& Behavior, University of Queens, USA \emph{smith@uoq.edu}}\\
}
\date{}
\hypersetup{pdfinfo={
Title={Zombie Paranoia in the Bronx: A Study in Psychosocial Perceptions},
Author={John Smith}
}}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Have a look at section 3.7 of the [hyperref package manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) for more information.

Comment: Your answer's just what I need, Ian, though I wish it had the full range of options shown in amorua's answer. Of course, there are a great many options and your link brings me to them. Thank you :-)

Comment: Ran pdflatex with these contents, but OSX Preview 5.0.3 still shows just the document name as the sidebars top level TOC item. Isn't this exactly what pdfinfo Title should change?

Comment: Note that `pdfinfo={` is **more powerful**, because you can create **custom** metadata entries, such as `Copyright` or `Source`, while the variant of using `pdfauthor=` etc. has limited entries (see all possible entries in @amorua's answer)

Comment: Can we somehow detect if hyperref is loaded and have a solution which works for both cases without commenting/uncommenting depending on if we decide to load hyperref?

Comment: @bilako --- `\ifdefined\hypersetup WHATEVER \else WHATEVER ELSE \fi`

Answer (score 15):

Indeed `\pdfinfo`
 does not work in combination with `hyperref`

Try the following

```
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={Author},%
            pdftitle={Your Title},%
            pdfsubject={Whatever},%
            pdfkeywords={one, two},%
            pdfproducer={LaTeX},%
            pdfcreator={pdfLaTeX}
}
```

Comment: Your answer's to the point, amorua, but I wish you'd included the link that Ian did.

Answer (score 5):

If I try typesetting your input and preview it with Skim, the Author and Title info are as you want, but not with Adobe Reader. If instead I write

```
\hypersetup{
  pdfinfo={
   Title={Zombie Paranoia in the Bronx: A Study in Psychosocial Perceptions},
   Author={John Smith},
  }
}
```

then also Adobe Reader shows the desired data.