# How to change the title of a PDF?

Tags: pdf

I am getting a bunch of PDF files from some other source, and I need to change the PDF title via a script, i.e. the title that you can inspect via pdfinfo for example. Does texlive come with some such tool / package? Or are there other packages? I have investigated pdftk and the pdftools, but not found anything so far.

Comment: This is not really a tex related questions, however pdftk can indeed do what you want. Have a look at the `update_info` command which either take a file or stdin input.

Comment: As @ArTourter said `pdftk` will do the job, here's a tutorial: http://sangonz.wordpress.com/2010/04/11/how-to-edit-pdf-metadata-maclinuxwindows/

Comment: TeX programs can produce PDF files, but not manipulate them. One way might be to import a complete PDF with `\includepdf` from `pdfpages` and set the title; but links in the included PDF will disappear.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not on-topic here and therefore got closed. However, I can tell you that `pdftk` has an `update_info` option which should allow you to change the PDF title in the meta-data.

Comment: Yup, ok. pdftk works and we can close this. :)

Comment: FYI, when generating PDFs from TeX (e.g. using markdown2pdf, which because it is part of [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/), uses TeX templates), [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26529/how-can-i-generate-pdf-metadata-from-latex) has the answer.