# Optimize TeX produced PDF for Search

Tags: packages, pdf, metadata

What are some tips for LaTeX that produce search-engine friendly PDF files?

For instance, if one does nothing, the default header title of the PDF file is "My Title" when uploaded to the web, which surely cannot be good for search-engines.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: I took a fair few tips from the gitinfo2 documentation .tex file, available on ctan and other places

Comment: Regarding meta data you may find your answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26529/60650

Comment: The hyperref supports a pdfkeywords option.