# How to provides title and author variable to hypersetup?

Tags: xetex, pdftex

I try to set dynamicaly pdf metadata with:

```
\def\date#1{\def\@date{#1}}
\def\author#1{\def\@author{#1}}
\def\title#1{\def\@title{#1}}
\def\subtitle#1{\def\@subtitle{#1}}
\def\location#1{\def\@location{#1}}
\def\thesisdirector#1{\def\@thesisdirector{#1}}
\def\thesiscodirector#1{\def\@thesiscodirector{#1}}
\def\discipline#1{\def\@discipline{#1}}
\def\doctoralschool#1{\def\@doctoralschool{#1}}
\def\doctoralschoolnumber#1{\def\@doctoralschoolnumber{#1}}
\def\nationalthesisnumber#1{\def\@nationalthesisnumber{#1}}

\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    final       = true,
    colorlinks  = true,
    urlcolor    = blue,
    citecolor   = blue,
    linkcolor   = MidnightBlue,
    unicode     = true,
    linktoc     = section,
    pdfauthor   = {\@author},
    pdfkeywords = {biocomputing, biotechnology, software , scientific},
    pdftitle    = {\@title},
    pdfsubject  = {Genomic expert annotation}   
}
\makeatother
```

or this

```
\makeatletter
\def\date#1{\def\@date{#1}}

\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{#1}\gdef\@@author{#1}}
\let\@@author\@empty
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}\gdef\@@title{#1}}
\let\@@title\@empty

\def\subtitle#1{\def\@subtitle{#1}}
\def\location#1{\def\@location{#1}}
\def\thesisdirector#1{\def\@thesisdirector{#1}}
\def\thesiscodirector#1{\def\@thesiscodirector{#1}}
\def\discipline#1{\def\@discipline{#1}}
\def\doctoralschool#1{\def\@doctoralschool{#1}}
\def\doctoralschoolnumber#1{\def\@doctoralschoolnumber{#1}}
\def\nationalthesisnumber#1{\def\@nationalthesisnumber{#1}}


\hypersetup{
    final       = true,
    colorlinks  = true,
    urlcolor    = blue,
    citecolor   = blue,
    linkcolor   = MidnightBlue,
    unicode     = true,
    linktoc     = section,
    pdfauthor   = {\@@author},
    pdfkeywords = {biocomputing, biotechnology, software , scientific},
    pdftitle    = {\@@title},
    pdfsubject  = {Genomic expert annotation}   
}
\makeatother
```

This piece of code is put right after required package into my cls file.

But that do not build:

```
You can't use `\spacefactor' in internal vertical mode. \maketitle
```

I agree with you is a common error. I found lot of report (some ref: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26529/how-can-i-generate-pdf-metadata-from-latex))

But each time the answer do not have a MWE or do not works

Thanks for your light

Comment: As you are complaining about answers about MWE you seem to know their importance. So can you please add MWE to your question instead of code fragments?

Comment: you have right, I should do it. I found my mistake. I put hypersetup command after required package declaration while title and author variable was defined before begin document. Moving the hypersetup declation after defnied variable fix my problem. Unfortunately I do not found how to do a lazy evaluation to let the hypersetup command into my cls file. Thanks @samcarter, I hope my answer is enough –

Comment: Good to hear, you could fix your problem. But please don't edit your question to include the answer, but provide an answer below. http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**

Problem was hypersetup declaration was into my cls file after required package. At this position variable was defined but set to their final values.
I move  the hypersetup statement after that title and author variable are set.
And that works.

in my cls file

```
\RequirePackage[xetex]{hyperref}
\def\date#1{\def\@date{#1}}
\let\@date\@empty

\def\author#1{\def\@author{#1}}
\let\@author\@empty

\def\title#1{\def\@title{#1}}
\let\@title\@empty

\def\keywords#1{\def\@keywords{#1}}
\let\@keywords\@empty
```

into main tex file:

```
\author{blah}
\title{blah}

\makeatletter
\hypersetup{%
    final       = true,
    colorlinks  = true,
    urlcolor    = blue,
    citecolor   = blue,
    linkcolor   = MidnightBlue,
    unicode     = true,
    linktoc     = section,
    pdflang     = fr-FR,
    pdfauthor   = {\@author},
    pdfkeywords = {\@keywords},
    pdftitle    = {\@title},
    pdfsubject  = {...}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
...
```