# Entering Data in LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, pdf, metadata

Oi, eu utilizo o LaTeX para o desenvolvimento dos meus trabalhos e afins, e uso o Mozilla Firefox como meu programa  padrão para abrir PDF.
Gostaria de saber se tem como inserir tais dados expostos no screenshot para que, caso seja aberto as propriedades do meu documento, aparacem: Título, Autor, Assunto, Palavra-chave.

---

[image: Data]

Comment: Google translate: Hi, I use LaTeX for the development of my work and the like, and I use Mozilla Firefox as my default program to open PDF. I would like to know if you can insert such exposed data in the screenshot so that if you open the properties of my document, it will appear: Title, Author, Subject, Keyword.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26529/14100

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.