# pdfcreator vs. pdfproducer - PDF Metadata in Hyperref Hypersetup

Tags: hyperref, pdf, metadata, git

I came across a comment under this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/26530/133604 :

> What's the difference between `pdfproducer` and `pdfcreator`?

Now, a lot of examples regarding the usage of hyperref and metadata use templates like [this one](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks#Customization):

```
\hypersetup{
...
pdfcreator={Creator},   % creator of the document
pdfproducer={Producer}, % producer of the document
....
}
```

Looking at the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf) did not help to solve the above question. Can you explain the difference between both?

Furthermore, I don't known which one to set explicitly and why I should use it.

For the moment I have been using the line

`pdfcreator={LaTeX with hyperref (gitREF, gitSHA)}`

where gitREF is set to `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` and gitSHA to `git rev-parse --short HEAD`. Being confronted to choose between pdfcreator and pdfproducer to store this data I am not sure which one makes more sense at least for my use case.

Comment: according to the pdf reference both should be set if a pdf is created by converting from another format. Then creator is the application which created the original document and producer the converter. E.g. if you convert from docx Creator=Word,  Producer=printtopdf. It doesn't really fit the production with a pdftex engine, but if you go through dvi, producer is e.g. ghostscript.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you. the standard values on my system seem to be (after running pdflatex) `Creator: LaTeX with hyperref` and `Producer: pdfTeX-1.40.21`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the PDF reference both should be set if a PDF is created by converting from another format. Then `creator` is the application which created the original document and `producer` the converter. E.g. if you convert from docx the Creator would be e.g. `Word XY`, and the producer for example some `print to pdf` driver.

If you create the PDF by using LaTeX together with some `dvi`-driver, then the creator is typically some variant of `LaTeX` and the producer e.g. `xdvipdfmx` or `Ghostscript` (which sets the producer automatically, you can't adjust this in the document).

It isn't quite clear if one should call a PDF creation with pdftex or luatex a `conversion`, but creator is here normally set to variant of `LaTeX` too, and the producer to the engine and its version.

If you create a PDF with Acrobat, it will set both to the name and version of the application: `Adobe Acrobat XY`

Comment: Thanks again! With *PDF reference* you mean this document: [PDF Reference](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf), in particular, Section **10.2.1 Document Information Dictionary**?

Comment: I think I checked in the pdf 2.0 reference (which you have to buy), but imho in 1.7 it says the same.